# Call a static method from other class in python

Tags: python, static-methods, attributeerror

I have a python file with name Pqr.py which contains a class holding a static method.

```
import subprocess

class Pqr:

    @staticmethod
    def callTheService(a,b,c):
       subprocess.call(a,b,c)
```

Now I am trying to access this static method from another class which is in other python file. Both .py files are located in same directory. The code in second file is,

```
import Pqr

class Rst:
    Pqr.callTheService("a", "b", "c")
```

When I try to run this, I get an error of **AttributeError: module 'Pqr' has no attribute 'callTheService'**

Could you please help me solve this error?

Comment: is your file named `Pqr.py`? You need to access the *class* not the module, so use `Pqr.Pqr.callTheService`. In python, you do not generally give the module the same name as a class (Python != Java). BTW, this would have been more obvious if you follow Python naming conventions. Generally, you use `lower_case` for module names, and avoid `camelCase` at all costs!

Comment: Here is the link to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Wow, @juanpa.arrivillaga you solved my problem within minutes! Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Hannu I mean, it *could* be a static method, why should it be a class method? More likely, it should just be a module level function.  So using a class here makes no sense at all, but I'm assuming that `Pqr` should be a class to begin with, and this is a toy example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem reading comments. I imported the class within the module. Here is the sample working code.

```
from Pqr import Pqr

class Rst:
    Pqr.callTheService("a", "b", "c")
```

Comment: You should probably rename your module. I'm not sure what you mean "I imported the file instead of the entire module", but it doesn't sound correct.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry I am new to Python, right now going through the documentation you shared with me.